# Storing/Buffering Files for quick access in MediaPlayer - File vs FileInputStream vs FileDescriptor

Tags: java, performance, file

I need to quickly, basically seemlessly, switch between videos in a android mediaplayer. For that I would like to store/buffer the videos as quick as possible.

At the moment, I save an ArrayList. To pass that file to the MediaPlayer, I use FileInputStream.getFD() to get the FileDescriptor.

I got the following statements from the javadoc of the respective classes:

- File: "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames."
- FileInputStream: "obtains input bytes from a file in a file system"
- FileDescriptor: "Instances of the file descriptor class serve as an opaque handle to the underlying machine-specific structure representing an open file"

In terms of performance, I dont really get what class would make a difference here.

When I switch between the videos, there is a short delay. Understandably. But I want to get this delay as low as I possibly can.

This is the gist of my code:

```
mVideoStreams = SomeClass.getMyVideos();
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

public void changeVideo(int number)
{
    mMediaPlayer.reset();

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mVideoStreams.get(number).getFD());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Is there a "fastest" way to pass these videos or even "buffer" them, so that they are in memory and can be quickly retreived?